# Why does firefox-nightly not produce sound when speaker-test works fine? | Permission errors | Pulseaudio | Arch Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, arch-linux, pulseaudio, i3

I am on Arch Linux install with i3-gaps. I have tried `speaker-test -t wav -c 2`, and both headphones and speakers work. Sound occasionally starts working when I play around with `sudo -u user pulseaudio -D --start` and `start-pulseaudio-x11`. The `pulseaudio` command only works with `sudo -u user` but fails if I `su user` and run the same command. The latter (sometimes) fails to connect when ran with root or `sudo -u user`, resulting in`pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused`. Switching into user with`su` and results in

```
E: [autospawn] core-util.c: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/0) is not owned by us (uid 1000), but by uid 0! (This could e.g. happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
W: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
```

Packages:

```
Alsa packages:
  ~ alsa-lib 1.2.2-1
  ~ alsa-plugins 1.2.2-1
  ~ alsa-topology-conf 1.2.2-2
  ~ alsa-ucm-conf 1.2.2-1
  - alsa-utils 1.2.2-1
Pulseaudio packages
  ~ libpulse 13.0-3
  ~ pulseaudio 13.0-3
  ~ pulseaudio-alsa 2-5
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question. If I am to run `pulseaudio -D --start` it results in an error, but `pulseaudio -D` only in a warning, and becomes functional